# Converting .xls to google spreadsheet in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have an .xls file stored in Google Drive. I want to convert it to the Google Sheets spreadsheet file format from Google Apps Script. Is there any way to do this without external solutions?

Answer (score 8):

**Updated 2024-03-22 - NEW for Drive API v3**

```
var xlsxBlob = xlsxFile.getBlob();
var resource = { 
  name : newFileName, 
  mimeType : MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, 
  parents: [driveFolderId] 
}; 
const file = Drive.Files.create(resource, xlsxBlob);
```

Docs:

- Drive.Files.create:
  developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create
- File parameters:
  developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files#File

---

**Below: DEPRECATED - applicable only for Drive API v2.**

This is now possible using the Advanced Drive service:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive

When using Drive.Files.insert, simply set the optional parameter "convert" to "true".

```
var file = {
    title: 'Converted Spreadsheet'
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, xlsxBlob, {
    convert: true
  });
```

This was also obtained from the above given [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1019)

Comment: Yep, already using it for a few years. Just forgot to update info here.

Comment: You can also set the destination folder by providing the "parents" parameter to Drive.Files.insert. Like so: `parents: [{"kind": "drive#parentReference", "id": "folder id"}]`

Comment: I'm getting "empty response". Any ideas?

Comment: To enable 'Drive' service, open Google Apps Script console, click on + icon next to Services and select 'Drive API'.

Comment: This requires some change now that Drive is on v3 instead of v2 of Drive API (link below for documentation). 
Use this instead:

////////////////////

var xlsxBlob = xlsxFile.getBlob();
var resource = {
  name : newFileName,
  mimeType : MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  parents: [driveFolderId]
};
const file = Drive.Files.create(resource, xlsxBlob);

////////////////////
Docs:
Drive.Files.create: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create
File parameters: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files#File

Answer (score 3):

Other than using the delivered 'upload' and convert functions, it's not currently available.  Requesting enhancement request here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1019

Comment: This answer is outdated since Google now provides the Advanced Drive Service. See Hameed's answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's the complete code to create a file in a particular folder**:
*(was a hint but was not completely apparent to me from @ben-visness comment)*

```
var file = { 
    "title": filename, 
    "parents": [{"id": folderId}]
};
file = Drive.Files.insert(file, blobObj, {
    "convert": true
});
```

**Note**: This will require enabling advanced Drive service from within Google Apps Script - *Menu > Resources > Advanced Google Services* AND *Menu > Resources > Advanced Google Services > Google API Console*.

Comment: This no longer works, see my comment above. on Riyafa's post.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I used to convert an Excel file into a Google Sheets file, with the same name and in the same folder.

```
var excel = DriveApp.getFileById(...);

var resource = {
   title : excel.getName(),
   mimeType : MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
   parents: [{id : folder.getId()}],
}

Drive.Files.insert(resource, excel.getBlob());
```

In my case, I already had a `folder` object available which represented the folder I wanted to save the sheet to, but you could just as easily get the folder of the original file using `excel.getParents()`.

You will also have to enable an Advanced Google Service called "Drive API" in order to use  `Drive.Files`. Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

Solution was originally derived from [this](https://www.labnol.org/code/20500-convert-microsoft-excel-xlsx-to-google-spreadsheet) article.

Comment: This no longer works, see my comment above. on Riyafa's post.