# Google Script - convert sheet to XLSX

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, file-conversion

I have this code that search new doc in drive folder, and send files via email

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var email = "xxx@gmail.com";      
var timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

var today     = new Date();
var oneDayAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);  
var startTime = oneDayAgo.toISOString();

var search = '(trashed = false or trashed = false) and (modifiedDate > "' +    startTime + '")';
var folder1 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('SaveToPDF').next();
var files1  = folder1.searchFiles(search);

var row = "", count=0;

while( files1.hasNext() ) {

var file1 = files1.next();

var fileName = file1.getName();
var fileURL  = file1.getUrl();
var lastUpdated =  Utilities.formatDate(file1.getLastUpdated(), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
var dateCreated =  Utilities.formatDate(file1.getDateCreated(), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")

row += "<li>" + lastUpdated + " <a href='" + fileURL + "'>" + fileName + "</a></li>";

sheet.appendRow([dateCreated, lastUpdated, fileName, fileURL]);

count++;
}
if (row !== "") {
row = "<p>" + count + " file(s) have changed in your Google Drive in the past 24 hours. Here's the list:</p><ol>" + row + "</ol>";
row +=  "<br><small>To stop these notifications, please <a href='" + ss.getUrl() + "'>click here</a> and choose <em>Uninstall</em> from the Drive Activity menu.<br/></small>";
MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Google Drive - File Activity Report", "", {htmlBody: row, cc: "xxx@gmail.com"} );
  }
```

I need to convert sheet files to XLSX format before send. 
Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can follow this [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20124-convert-google-spreadsheet-to-excel) on how to convert the current Google Spreadsheet to Excel XLSX format and then emails the file as an attachment to the specified user using `getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel()` method.

```
function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){

  try {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

    blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");

    MailApp.sendEmail("amit@labnol.org", "Google Sheet to Excel", "The XLSX file is attached", {attachments: [blob]});

  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

Here are some similar threads which might help:

- [Google apps script to email google spreadsheet excel version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712137/google-apps-script-to-email-google-spreadsheet-excel-version)
- [Converting .xls to google spreadsheet in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681873/converting-xls-to-google-spreadsheet-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: How can I convert only one sheet by name to Excel, rather than the entire workbook?