# Macro button to add row (with formulas from row below) in Excel while maintaining headers

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to duplicate a working script from Google Sheets into Excel. The goal is to copy the second row of the active sheet and paste the formatting, data validation and formulas into a new row above. This is intended to place a new (formatted with formulas and data validation) in row 2 below the headers.

Here's the google script

```
// global
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function addFirstRow() {
    var firstRow = 2;
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
    var range = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    sh.insertRowsBefore(firstRow, 1);
    var newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
    newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
    newRange.setFormulas(formulas);
}
```

Here's a video of the google sheets in action
https://youtu.be/OCinWCApypw

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Refer this link, I think it addresses the same issue and will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765110/google-script-convert-sheet-to-xlsx

Comment: The macro should look similar to this one. However, I don't know how to program it to copy row 2 and insert an empty row in its place thus shifting all rows down. 

`Sub Copy_One_Row_Below()
With Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 16))
.Offset(1).Insert shift:=xlDown
.Copy
.Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
.Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With
Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 2) = "=" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Address & "+1"
End Sub
`

Answer (score 0):

So you just need this or I didn't understand well ?

```
   Sub Test()
    Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("3:3").Copy
    Rows("2:2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = false
   End Sub
```

Comment: This is close.. How does one insert the row with the formatting, data validation, and formulas while omitting the content. i.e. the inserted row should be blank.

Comment: `xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats` instead of `xlPasteAll` should work

Comment: Vincent is right, you can replace the parameter "xlPasteAll", with what you need [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlpastetype-enumeration-excel) . If you need multiple parameters you can retype the line each time as needed.
In your exemple `Rows("2:2").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats` and next line `Rows("2:2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation`