# Apps Script Drive.Files.insert not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to convert a .pdf file to text using Apps Script called from a Google Sheet.  I am using the Advanced Drive API service (it seems the only way to do it).  I have added the Drive API service and deployed the app as an API.  The app runs, uploads the pdf from users pc to a drive file.  The file is passed to code copied from Github which should perform the conversion but fails with

> TypeError: Drive.Files.insert is not a function

I don't think this is the code in error but maybe how I have configured the Apps Script.  I am struggling to find any documentation that can help me see where I have gone wrong.

The function which fails in line 17 const { id, title } = Drive.Files.insert( :

```js
/*
 * Convert PDF file to text
 * @param {string} fileId - The Google Drive ID of the PDF
 * @param {string} language - The language of the PDF text to use for OCR
 * return {string} - The extracted text of the PDF file
 */

const convertPDFToText = (fileId, language) => {
  fileId = fileId || '18FaqtRcgCozTi0IyQFQbIvdgqaO_UpjW'; // Sample PDF file
  language = language || 'en'; // English

  // Read the PDF file in Google Drive
  const pdfDocument = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

  // Use OCR to convert PDF to a temporary Google Document
  // Restrict the response to include file Id and Title fields only
  const { id, title } = Drive.Files.insert(
    {
      title: pdfDocument.getName().replace(/\.pdf$/, ''),
      mimeType: pdfDocument.getMimeType() || 'application/pdf',
    },
    pdfDocument.getBlob(),
    {
      ocr: true,
      ocrLanguage: language,
      fields: 'id,title',
    }
  );

  // Use the Document API to extract text from the Google Document
  const textContent = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody().getText();

  // Delete the temporary Google Document since it is no longer needed
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);

  // (optional) Save the text content to another text file in Google Drive
  const textFile = DriveApp.createFile(`${title}.txt`, textContent, 'text/plain');
  return textContent;
};
```

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331989/7215091)?

Comment: Thanks, but both solutions use the Advanced Drive API and  I can't get the API functions to work - so I don't think it would get me any further forward.

Comment: But your question is about Drive.Files.insert and that is from Advanced Drive API

Comment: Did you enable the Advanced Drive API in the Google Cloud Panel?

Comment: No, I don't think I have done that.  I suspect that's why it's not working.  How would I do that?

Comment: go to the script editor project settings and make sure your project is a gcp project and then click on the project number and go to the library.  Search for "Drive API".  When you find it go to it you will see a place to click on to enable it.  You will also have to enable in the script editor under services.  You may also have to add additional scopes to you appscript.json file.

Comment: OK, both enabled.  I now get an authorisation issue so can no longer run the script.  I am drifting into Google Cloud projects - way out of my current league and I'm stumbling around in the dark.  I will try the Drive.Files.copy option from your original comment - assuming that will work without the Advanced Drive API?

Comment: Drive.Files.Copy is part of the Advaned Drive API also.

Comment: I literally type the oauth scopes right into my appsscript.json manifest file.  Keep in mind everything is out of your range until you learn how to use it and then it is in your range.

Comment: Would you mind messaging on this?  I am persevering!  I have created a Standard cloud project, enabled the Advanced Drive API, enabled the Drive API and copied all the oauth links into the manifest file.  Still the same exception on Drive.Files.insert.  I don't really want to load up this conversation until I can get to a solution and then publish.  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: It runs on my spreadsheet and the only drive scopes I have are: `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity",`  I  suspect all you need is drive.  Also have you enabled it in the editor menu under services?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256304/discussion-between-jim-burke-and-cooper).

Comment: It looks like you in luck Tanaike's here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your error message of `TypeError: Drive.Files.insert is not a function`, on December 11, 2023, Drive API of Advanced Google services could use v3. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/docs/release-notes#December_11_2023) And, now, when Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google services, Drive API v3 is used as the default version. And, in Drive API v3, `insert` method is not included in `Drive.Files`. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When I saw your showing script, it seemed that it was for Drive API v2. So, if you want to use your showing script, please set Drive API v3 to v2 in Advanced Google services as follows.

[image]

or

[image]

And, as another approach, if your showing script is converted to Drive API v3, it becomes as follows.

```js
/*
 * Convert PDF file to text
 * @param {string} fileId - The Google Drive ID of the PDF
 * @param {string} language - The language of the PDF text to use for OCR
 * return {string} - The extracted text of the PDF file
 */

const convertPDFToText = (fileId, language) => {
  fileId = fileId || '18FaqtRcgCozTi0IyQFQbIvdgqaO_UpjW'; // Sample PDF file
  language = language || 'en'; // English

  // Read the PDF file in Google Drive
  const pdfDocument = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

  // Use OCR to convert PDF to a temporary Google Document
  // Restrict the response to include file Id and Title fields only
  const { id, name } = Drive.Files.create(
    {
      name: pdfDocument.getName().replace(/\.pdf$/, ''),
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS,
    },
    pdfDocument.getBlob(),
    {
      ocrLanguage: language,
      fields: 'id,name',
    }
  );

  // Use the Document API to extract text from the Google Document
  const textContent = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody().getText();

  // Delete the temporary Google Document since it is no longer needed
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);

  // (optional) Save the text content to another text file in Google Drive
  const textFile = DriveApp.createFile(`${name}.txt`, textContent, 'text/plain');
  return textContent;
};
```

This modified script works with Drive API v3.

#### Note:

- If an error related to the scopes occurs, please remove a property of `oauthScopes` from `appsscript.json` and run the script again. If an error is not removed, please create a new Google Apps Script project and copy and paste the script and enable Drive API v2 or v3 and test it again.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script release notes on December 11, 2023](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/docs/release-notes#December_11_2023)
- [Method: files.insert of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/insert)
- [Method: files.create of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create)
- You can also see the official document of "[Drive API v2 & v3 comparison reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/v2-to-v3-reference)".

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed it and it is working perfectly now.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Jim Burke Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.