# Is there a script that can delete resolved comments on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, field

I am trying to add a script that removes resolved comments on Google Sheets but I keep receiving this error message: "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.comments.list failed with error: The 'fields' parameter is required for this method." I have tried adding a 'field' parameter based on other suggestions from this forum but none seem to be working. This is my current code that is not working:

```
function deleteResolvedComments() {
  const id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  const comments = Drive.Comments.list(id).items;
  comments.forEach(comment => {
    if(comment.status === 'resolved'){
      Drive.Comments.remove(id, comment.commentId);
    }
  });
}
```

I have tried adding a field multiple different ways but the same error message keeps returning.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing script, I thought that your script is for Drive API v2. But, from your error message of `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.comments.list failed with error: The 'fields' parameter is required for this method.`, I guessed that you are enabling Drive API v3. Because in the current stage, when Drive API is enabled at Advance Google services, version 3 is used as the default version. This might be related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77675659). If my guess was correct, such an error occurs.

In this case, there are the following 2 modification patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

Please change the version of Drive API from v3 to v2. By this, your script works.

#### Pattern 2:

When you use Drive API v3, please modify your script as follows.

```js
function deleteResolvedComments() {
  const id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  const comments = Drive.Comments.list(id, { fields: "*" }).comments;
  comments.forEach(comment => {
    if (comment.resolved === true) {
      Drive.Comments.remove(id, comment.id);
    }
  });
}
```

This modified script can be used with Drive API v3.

#### Reference:

- [Method: comments.list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/comments/list)