# ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-app-maker

In Google App Maker, I am writing a function in ServerScript that will convert a user-uploaded Excel spreadsheet to Google spreadsheet. I am using this piece of code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35597644/9878092), but I am getting

> ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined.

I tried using the line of code that I got directly from the link:

```
file = Drive.Files.insert(file, xlsxBlob, {
```

and my own edited version:

```
file = Drive.Files.update(file, ssFileID, xlsxBlob, {
```

Where `ssFileID` is the file id of the pre-made Google Sheet I want to insert the data from a user-uploaded Excel spreadsheet into. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Did you make sure to enable the Drive API under App Settings>Advanced Services?

Comment: @MarkusMalessa Just enabled the Drive API, it solved the error! Thank you so much!

Comment: Make sure you read the links in answers, not just copy (and attribute) the code ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have multiple issues:

1. "Drive" is not defined" error, see this

Open menu from your script ( the place you start with Code.gs) and use :
**Resources** - **Advanced Google services** and check on the **Drive API v2**

2. Use files from drive to change and upload

   - your source code can identify the files and used ;
   - define the resources and blob ;
   - enable the Advanced Drive API Service: var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, ...) ;

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem. It was resolved by adding Drive Services to the project. Snapshot attached to show how to do it.

Add Drive :

[image: Add Services]

Answer (score 1):

Run this line first:
from google.colab import drive