# Why does "ReferenceError: Drive is not defined" keep occuring frequently?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-apps-script-addon, google-apps-script-api

`const file = Drive.Files.insert({ title: 'Temp.pdf' }, blob, { ocr: true, ocrLanguage: "en" });`

I have enabled Drive API(v2) from **Resources->Advanced Google Services** and also enabled Drive API in **Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard** for that particular project.

But this doesn't look like a one time activity. The error **ReferenceError: Drive is not defined** keeps coming every now and then. When I enable Drive API from **Resources->Advanced Google Services**, there is no error for some time and it comes again after some time. The setting in **Resources->Advanced Google Services** is not persisted.

Why is it not persisted? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823383/referenceerror-drive-is-not-defined)

Comment: No. I have already tried that. The problem is I need to keep doing that setting. It's not persisted.

Comment: Have you gone to `https://console.cloud.google.com` to enable the library?

Comment: Yes. I have done that.

Comment: Hi there @Ekalavya! To prevent any project misconfiguration, could you create a blank new script and copy your codelines there?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that reference error was occurring only after I perform a clasp push. Resolved.