# Convert xlsb to google sheets using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, xlsb

I would like to convert xlsb format file into google sheets using google app script.

Comment: You can try referring here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681873/converting-xls-to-google-spreadsheet-in-google-apps-script.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

### This is not possible

Referring to the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/40608?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), Google Docs supports:

```
.xls (if newer than Microsoft® Office 95)
.xlsx
.xlsm
.xlt
.xltx
.xltm
.ods
.csv
.txt
.tsv
.tab
```

If you need to use an XSLB file, first convert it using Office or another converter to one of the above formats.

Alternatively, if you are skilled and brave, you can tackle the [XLSB Specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xlsb/acc8aa92-1f02-4167-99f5-84f9f676b95a) to see if there is a way to convert the binary to something understandable using Apps Script!

If this is important to you and your business, I suggest you file a well justified [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/) so that Google might consider implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible.

You need to use some MS's tools for converting xlsb to xlsx before anything.